# Traceback NameError in python tutorial

Tags: python

I'm reading an online python tutorial book from [here](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/python_en-control_flow/). The code is listed below. When I execute the code, I can type words into it but then it gave me the error below. What is the wrong with the code?

On a related note, if you have a better resource for leaning python, please let me know. I'm looking for one that is online and updated often (ex: railstutorial.org). The resource I am using have plenty of errors even this early in the book. Thanks.

```
Enter something : programmig is fun
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "break.py", line 5, in <module>
    s = input('Enter something : ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'programmig' is not defined

#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: break.py

while True:
    s = input('Enter something : ')
    if s == 'quit':
        break
    print('Length of the string is', len(s))
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is python 3 code. It seems like you're running it with python 2.

Run `python --version` to check which version of python you are using.

Comment: I have python 2.7.2 which is sad because the book explicitly said that he is using python 2.7.2.

Comment: Well, actually he said he was using python 3 then switch and now he has a mixture of python 2 and 3 codes lol

Comment: Odd. I can tell this is 3 because: `print` is a function and `input` is expected to act like the old `raw_input`. Also, it runs just as you'd expect in python 3.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` doesn't get a string, so it thinks that `programmig` is a variable. You can type the input you want in quotes to solve this.
A better way however, is to use `raw_input`, which returns a string.
So either do `Enter something : 'programmig is fun'`, not recommended, or do `s = raw_input('Enter something : ')` **recommended way**

The cause of the confusion is that the book is probably for python 3, which has a different `input`, and also a different `print`, while you are using python 2.x.

Comment: This is true for python 2, but judging by the function `print`, this is python 3.

Comment: @MatthewAdams, so probably he's running python 2.x while having a python 3 tut.

Comment: I'd bet that's what's going on.